# ASP - How to get URL of Referring Site

Tags: asp-classic

This is an ASP question, not ASP.Net.

Assume there are two sites:

1. www.domain-1.com
2. www.domain-2.com

www.domain-1.com has a redirection URL in IIS that points to www.domain-2.com. In www.domain-2.com, I need to know the URL of the referring site (e.g. in this case, it would be www.domain-1.com). How is this done?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

referer = Request.ServerVariables ("HTTP_REFERER")

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when it's an IIS redirect. When it's coming from an href, it works fine, though.

Comment: It is not 100% reliable.  It is not always set by the users browser and some spyware/privacy apps can remove it from the get request as well.

However, there is any easy solution to this problem if you have access to the redirect code.  You can change it to include a query string variable with the source host so www.domain-1.com redirects the user to www.domain-2.com/?source=www.domain-1.com

Comment: it work perfectly when the page is called by an <a> element, but the variable is empty when called by a rediect or when the page is called directly from the url.