# Forcing an asp page to load on Windows server when an image file is requested via Google image search

Tags: image, iis, redirect, asp-classic, windows-server-2003

Is there a way to force an asp page to load whenever an image file is requested on its own?

What I would like to do is not just show the image when someone clicks through from a Google image search but load a page with code to allow me to provide further information around that image.

Comment: So, the perpetual question: What have *you* tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I have no idea how or if it can be done. Obviously if an asp page is loaded I can do it but if it is just the image that is viewed (via a "View Image" on Google Images) I would like it redirected to a page where I can wrap the image with code.

Comment: So I would recommend a bit of research in the first instance. You could possibly start by looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286327/asp-how-to-get-url-of-referring-site), if you're looking at Classic ASP (as per your tag) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803027/finding-the-referring-url-that-brought-a-user-to-my-site) if you're talking about ASP.NET.

Comment: ty. I spent a lot of time researching with no luck. Sorry if I haven't made my requirement clear, I will try to elaborate. The post you referred me to talks about getting the "referer" which I know how to do. It isn't really an asp question as the request to load the image will go straight to the server rather than to an asp page. I am trying to determine whether it is possible to intercept the image request and say that if the image has been loaded via a visit from an external site then redirect it to an asp page passing in the image name so I can wrap it in code. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I did find [this](http://antezeta.com/news/avoid-search-engine-indexing), though this isn't really what you're looking for.

I also found this about [ISAPI filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610(v=vs.90).aspx) that can be applied to IIS, though you'd need to write this as a library (DLL) and, to be honest, I know less than nothing about this.

It's probably not much of a help to you, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you anyway Paul. Appreciate it!